PostgreSQL one to many relationship transposing second table
I have two tables, for sake of simplification let's call them employees and employee_comms:
employee:



id
name
dept




1
Jane
Maintenance


2
Joe
Design



employee_comms:



id
contact_id
comms_type
comms_value




1
1
email
jane@examplemail.com


2
1
phone
555 324 6573


3
2
email
joe@examplemail.com


4
2
phone
555 201 5843



Currently, comms_type can be only either phone or email.
I wrote a query to filter employees by department and show email and phone for each:
SELECT
  d.id,
  d.name,
  d.dept,
  p.comms_value as phone,
  e.comms_value as email
FROM
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM employee
    WHERE dept = 'Design'
  ) AS d
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT contact_id, comms_value
    FROM employee_comms
    WHERE comms_type = 'phone'
  ) AS p ON (d.id = p.contact_id)
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT contact_id, comms_value
    FROM employee_comms
    WHERE comms_type = 'email'
  ) AS e ON (d.id = e.contact_id);

The result is a table where the second table is transposed with single, unique-rows where no employee values are duplicated (id, name):



id
name
dept
phone
email




2
Joe
Design
joe@examplemail.com
555 201 5843



It currently solves my needs, but I keep thinking that there should be a more efficient solution, given that I am querying twice the employee_comms table and it could become a performance issue when the employee_comms table grows large (and it will).
Q: Is there a more efficient approach?

How To Get Answers To SQL Server Performance Questions
